# GWT: Referencing deprecated class SerializableException

Tags: java, gwt

When using GWT I get following warning:

```
Referencing deprecated class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializableException'
```

While it's only a warning, it's dead annoying having to look at every single time I run the project.

The warning occours since my RPC throws java.lang.Exception, and thus never actually uses the SerializableException, but GWT isn't clever enough to figure that out.

Is there a option to turn off the warning, or fix this, besides compiling my own version of the gwt-user/gwt-servlet libraries?

Thanks.

Edit: To clarify, this is GWT 2.0, and the project is being run from the Google Plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone on the GWT's Google Group [suggested](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/20e53cbe28c9d4b2) using [`SerializationException`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/SerializationException.html) instead of just Exception. Although, the javadocs for [`SerializableException`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/SerializableException.html) suggest that `Exception` should be fine too :/ Which version of GWT are you using?

> Deprecated. As of GWT 1.5, Exception
>   implements Serializable and can be
>   used in place of this [SerializableException] class

Comment: GWT 2.0, with Java 1.5, so there's little meaning in using SerializationException precisely because of this. And it wouldn't make a lot of sense to use a deprecated class when this is precisely what the warning is about!

Comment: `SerializationException` is not deprecated (don't confuse it with `SerializableException`). And by using it explicitly you will tell the GWT compiler which classes it should expect - instead of pulling in everything related that extends `Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

[Lombardi's blog has a discussion](http://development.lombardi.com/?p=1169#more-1169) of why *exactly* this is happening in the source.

Yeah, it's silly for Google to claim throwing `Exception` is a fine thing to do when it generates a lot of unnecessary JavaScript for subclasses of `Exception` and, in your case, generates warnings about those subclasses.

But this is all the more reason to throw a more specific exception (one that doesn't have a deprecated descendant). Unchecked exceptions on your RPC can still be handled by an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the loglevel of the gwt compiler. It seems like you have set yours to "warn", set it to info to get rid of the message.
If you are using eclipse do the following steps:

1. right click on the project
2. Google >> GWT Complie
3. Set the Log Level to info

Comment: I don't compile GWT if I can avoid it , but uses the hot-swap of code with the Eclipse GWT plugin to Jetty. So I need to set the logging options elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Although extending `SerializationException` is a workaround, the contract of `SerializationException` indicates that it should not be used as a parent class of your custom RPC exceptions. It's there to indicate issues with the serialization itself and not with the logic within your services.

The underlying issue is that the compiler generates unnecessary code. To avoid the error simply make sure that your code does not use `SerializableException` anymore and add the following line to your module descriptor.

```
<extend-configuration-property name="rpc.blacklist" value="com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializableException"/>
```

Once the compile issue is fixed, you can remove the line again. Here is a link to the issue you might wanna star/follow:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4438